Run Roboelectric in Unit Testing and Most Efficient way to perform instrument test at physical device
I'm doing some old codelab on testing here, But in the codelab it uses Roboelectric in UnitTest folder, but when I run that it stuck on this part

Here's the code.
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TasksViewModelTest {

    // Subject under test
    private lateinit var tasksViewModel: TasksViewModel

    // Executes each task synchronously using Architecture Components.
    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setupViewModel() {
        tasksViewModel = TasksViewModel(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    }


    @Test
    fun addNewTask_setsNewTaskEvent() {

        // When adding a new task
        tasksViewModel.addNewTask()

        // Then the new task event is triggered
        val value = tasksViewModel.newTaskEvent.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertThat(
            value.getContentIfNotHandled(), (not(nullValue()))
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun getTasksAddViewVisible() {

        // When the filter type is ALL_TASKS
        tasksViewModel.setFiltering(TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS)

        // Then the "Add task" action is visible
        assertThat(tasksViewModel.tasksAddViewVisible.getOrAwaitValue(), `is`(true))
    }

}

Well I know that the purpose of the UnitTest is to run the test faster, I on the later codelab it stated that it's faster to mock / fake the repository and pass it to the viewModel rather than using context and instantiate the viewModel (which remove the AndroidJUnit4 test runner) and remove the roboelectric test that takes ages to run.

My question is that so does the Roboelectric fall into the Instrumented test (which belong to the AndroidTest folder) or the unitTest, because it seems I can't run the test because it hang indefinately.

Also my other question, is how to setup your physical device for instrument and end to end testing efficiently. In many cases, you need to install the app, activate the Display pop up windows while running background for each app and run the testing. Does there any alternative way of doing the instrument / end to end testing in the physical device?


Thanks for reading this. And It will probably my reminder to doing testing in the future
I look up at some SO question about running test on physical device, but none of that are satisfy my question.
